# Magento price format without rounding the number

Tags: magento

I have the following price

$price  = 7.358;

I want the following result after formatting it till two digit after the decimal

$result = 7.35 but not the following

$result = 7.36;

How can i do this in the Magento.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would have to rewrite [Mage_Directory_Model_Currency](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php). This class has a `format()` method.

**Original version:**

```
public function format($price, $options=array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
{
    return $this->formatPrecision($price, 2, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
}
```

If you follow the call to formatPrecision you will see that the rounding boils down to `Zend_Currency` and you don't have any influence on it besides the precision. So you will have to round down in the format method before all that happens.

**Updated version:**

```
public function format($price, $options=array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
{
    $price = bcdiv($price, 1, 2);
    return $this->formatPrecision($price, 2, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
}
```

Note that you should never edit core files. A quick and dirty way to make this change would be to copy the file from `app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php` and modify this copy. But the recommended "Magento way" is to make a rewrite of the class. Look up "Magento model rewrite" if you don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you want this to happen, you can modify the display template instead of mucking with core code.  ie., if on catalog / product view pages, you can move catalog/product/price.phtml into your theme folder and create formatting functions.